# Android Drawable for App Dashboard Image Buttons

Tags: android, drawable, imagebutton, dashboard

I want to create a dashboard screen for my Android Native app, the Dashboard will have 9 ImageButtons but i am having difficulties on the size ratios for the Images in my drawable folders so that my Dashboard will be compatible on all (most) devices.

I want the 9 Image Buttons to fill the whole dahsboard with allowance being given to spaces between the buttons

Please can you give me an indication as to the sizes for my images and which drawable folders i need to place them in

Answer (score 0):

[Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) is the first place to look for regarding the icon sizes. The sizes and folders as per the documentation is as follows. Note that it is for icons like actionbar icons like search. For homescreen type icons you need to magnify as per your need.

1. **drawable-ldpi** not required
2. **drawable-mdpi**  48x48 px this is the base other resolution are factor of this base
3. **drawable-hdpi** 72x72 px 1.5 times base
4. **drawable-xhdpi** 108x108 px 2 times base
5. **drawable-xxhdpi** 144x144 px 3 times base
6. **drawable-xxxhpi** 192x192 px 4 times base

Also note that images will have padding associated with it and usually have transparent background. Also for people looking for official android icons here's the [download link](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html).